# playframework 2 jsRoutes is not defined in the zentasks tutorial

Tags: playframework-2.0

I've been working on the zentasks tutorial on the play framework site.  I am on this part of the tutorial

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaGuide6

It worked fine last night but when I woke up this morning I got an error in firefox->firebug jsRoutes is not defined.  I could scroll up in the code and click on the /assets/javascripts/routes in my head and there it was, the javascript had jsRoutes in it.  I had not changed anything but just in case, I had a copy of the zentasks application from the sample folder that comes with play.  I ran it and got the same error.  I was worried that I had changed something and just forgot in both my written version and the copied version of the zentasks application.  So I again copied the zentasks application from the sample folder and ran it.  It worked, no error and no issues clicking buttons in the application.  So I figured I had changed something and forgot and I was ready to start tracking down the problem.

Then something strange happened.  I ran the application that I was writing my self and IT WORKED!!! The error was gone.  I tried the first copy I made and it worked also.  I then tried the web browser built into eclipse with my version of the application and it didn't work.  Then I tried to run it in chrome and I received the same error "jsRoutes is not defined" yet I could navigate up and click on the javascript source /assets/javascripts/routes and I could see the jsRoutes in the script.  I continued on down the tutorial because it was working in firefox.  At the end of the tutorial you test the webpages with jUnit.  The tests failed with the same error "jsRoutes" is not defined.  I'm including screen shots. Can anyone help with this?

[image: the Initial Error]

[image: the link to the script]

[image: the script showing the definition of jsRoutes]

[image: working in firefox]

[image: error in the test console]

Answer (score 3):

I have been fighting with the same issue the last two hours, and the error is dumb but not easy to see.

The secret is in the file `conf/routes`: if you have something like this:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

GET     /login                          controllers.Application.login()

POST    /login                      controllers.Application.authenticate()

GET     /logout                     controllers.Application.logout()

POST    /projects                   controllers.Projects.add()
POST    /projects/groups            controllers.Projects.addGroup()
DELETE  /projects/:project          controllers.Projects.delete(project: Long)
PUT     /projects/:project          controllers.Projects.rename(project: Long)

GET     /projects/:project/tasks    controllers.Tasks.index(project: Long)
POST    /projects/:project/tasks    controllers.Tasks.add(project: Long, folder: String)


GET     /assets/javascripts/routes          controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

When javascriptRoutes is tried to be downloaded, it is not downloaded correctly because of the rule `GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)`, which have higher priority. Instead, this rule has to be at the end of `conf/routes`, so the file should have something like this:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()

GET     /login                          controllers.Application.login()

POST    /login                      controllers.Application.authenticate()

GET     /logout                     controllers.Application.logout()

POST    /projects                   controllers.Projects.add()
POST    /projects/groups            controllers.Projects.addGroup()
DELETE  /projects/:project          controllers.Projects.delete(project: Long)
PUT     /projects/:project          controllers.Projects.rename(project: Long)

GET     /projects/:project/tasks    controllers.Tasks.index(project: Long)
POST    /projects/:project/tasks    controllers.Tasks.add(project: Long, folder: String)


GET     /assets/javascripts/routes          controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

With that solution, I think your error will disappear =).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem.  my solution was to compare my main.coffee file with the one in the working zentask application in the sample library.  turns out there was an indentation issue in my code - once that was corrected it ran fine. whitespace is significant in coffeescript, and i believe the default setting is 2 spaces for an ident.

Comment: I also had an indentation issue. I was trying to find the issue on and immediately around the line containing jsRoutes but the indentation problem was actually elsewhere.